# You cannot save reviews in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the review control code I removed from the code last `public ActionResult Edit ([Bind (Exclude = "Name")]` I should be able to edit and change the review and unfortunately, I can't find the problem.

```
    [Authorize]
    public class ReviewsController : BaseController
    {
        // GET: Reviews
        public ActionResult Index([Bind (Prefix ="Id")]int productId)
        {
            var product = _db.Products.Find(productId);

            if(product != null)
            {
                return View(product);
            }

            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        public ActionResult Create(int productId)
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Review model)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.Name = User.Identity.Name;
                _db.Reviews.Add(model);
                _db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ProductId });
            }
            return View(model);
        }
        public ActionResult Edit (int id)
        {
            var review = _db.Reviews.Find(id);

            if (review.Name == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                if (review != null)
                {
                    return View(review);
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Products");
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Review model)
        {
            if (model.Name == User.Identity.Name)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _db.Entry(model).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                    _db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = model.ProductId });
                }
            }
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Below is where you want to edit and save the review

[image]

What do I need to do to be able to edit the review and save.

Where in this code should I change something or somewhere else there may be a problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I need edit comment and save later such as a screen.

Comment: I can't read and change the reviews as in the screenshot, I don't know where I made the error or is it a problem in the controller.

Comment: Well, what is the solution to this problem in order to be able to change editable comments.